# MySQL Stored Procedure Date Not Incrementing, loop not terminating

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert a sequence of datetimes into a table. The times are supposed to increment by 15 minutes, so I get, for example

- 1/1/2019 00:00
- 1/1/2019 00:15
- 1/1/2019 00:30
- 1/1/2019 01:00

However what I actually get is

- 1/1/2019 00:00
- 1/1/2019 00:00
- 1/1/2019 00:00
- 1/1/2019 00:00

This is a **really** simple loop and I just can't see what I'm missing here.

The code is from another post on SO.

Thanks,

Terry

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `FillCalendar`(IN `start_date` DATE, IN `end_date` DATE)

BEGIN
    DECLARE crt_date DATE;
    SET crt_date = start_date;
    WHILE crt_date <= end_date DO
        INSERT IGNORE INTO Schedule(StartTime) VALUES(crt_date);
        SET crt_date = ADDDATE(crt_date, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
    END WHILE;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the variable as `DATETIME` so that it can hold the time of day. `DATE` can only hold a date, and the time is always `00:00`.

```
DECLARE crt_date DATETIME;
```

You may want to change the procedure parameters to be `DATETIME` as well.

Comment: Unbelievable. I've been staring at those few lines for hours. It would be nice if it threw an error when I tried to add minutes to a datatype that couldn't hold it.  THANK YOU! I'll mark your answer as "answer" as soon as SO lets me. It says I have to wait.

Comment: I'm surprised the code doesn't go into an infinite loop, since adding 15 minutes doesn't actually do anything to a `DATE`, so you'll never get to `end_date`.

Comment: it *does* go into an infinite loop. I had to kill the process from mysqladmin.